# Any way to use WGS84 latlng to dynamically get state plane EPSG code? Either javascript or PHP

Tags: state-plane

I am developing an online project that needs to be able to accept a WGS84 lat lng anywhere in the lower 48 states and produce the corresponding state plane coordinates.

Once I know the state plane EPSG code then I can use http://spatialreference.org to get the parameters for that state plane zone and then use proj4js to convert the latlng to state plane.

But I am missing a piece.

Is there a way with javascript or PHP to find out the correct state plane EPSG code for a WGS84 latlng?

Is there some kind of REST API I can call that will return the EPSG code?

Comment: This isn't really a coding issue, it is a spatial operation.  In order to figure out the proper EPSG code, you need to know what state plane zone the point falls into.  The zones are clearly defined, and I think there is an existing layer out there of the zone boundaries.  You would need to do an intersection between your lat/lon point with the zone boundaries, then the return from that you could use to feed the conversion process.

Comment: The way to do it in general would be to take the point as part of an SQL query to feed into a backend database to perform the intersection.  My thinking is that php may be better suited as it would keep all the processing on the server side.  What options do you have for installing a spatial database to hold the zone boundary layer and do the intersect operation?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I see this layer with State plane zones but it is not good at small scales.  I'll keep looking.  http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9e1a1714b2804858b49a4c19ab8a447c

Comment: Ok, I found a WMS service showing state plane zones.  That WMS supports GetFeatureInfo so hopefully it will tell me the EPSG code.  I found that WMS data at http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/united-states-stateplane-zones-nad83/resource/af6dad18-edc5-4f4c-a6dd-58600955cb41.  Here is a map that displays that WMS: http://bit.ly/1aGZ0CI

Comment: I would suggest that instead of using a map that has an unknown level of accuracy, that you may want to build your own layer.  All of the zones in the state plan systems are built with edges that correspond to either state boundaries, or county boundaries within the states.  This was done to ensure that all of the coordinates in one county would fall in the same zone.  Therefore, it may be worth taking the layer you have found, and finding a higher quality layer of US states and counties, and tagging these with the appropriate zone name.

Comment: I would be surprised if the service gave the EPSG code. It might give the FIPS code which you will still have to map to EPSG code.

Comment: Here is a site with an XLS file of county names and FIPS codes.  http://home.comcast.net/~rickking04/gis/spc.htm   I will likely add the EPSG codes and host that data on my server in some manner.  Then I should be able to find a GIS server that my code can query for the county name and then xmlhttprequest over to my server to get the EPSG code and away I go.  That is my plan unless something better comes along.  I am rather surprised there is no 'off the shelf' way to use a latlng to get a state plane EPSG code.

Comment: Perhaps your (implicit) assumptions are based on "everyone lives in my country" and "everyone uses my tools and has my workflow", so "everyone would have already needed this". That isn't so. This is the only gis.SE question tagged state-plane (and there is no definition)...